# Equations where one side may not exist

Tags: analysis

Every now and then, I encounter an equation (in analysis, usually) that needs to be interpreted as, "if one side exists, then the other side exists, and then the two sides are equal."

This prompted me to ask, are there examples of equations where one side might exist when the other side does not, but if both sides exist, then they are equal? I can't recall ever encountering such a thing in practice.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_density

Comment: If a function on $[a,b]$ is Riemann integrable, then it is Lebesgue integrable, and their integrals agree. But the Lebesgue integral might exist while the other does not. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @ElliotG : Yes, that's a pretty good example, but I should have clarified that I'd like an example where either side could exist but the other does not.

Comment: @WillJagy : I don't quite understand your suggestion. If the upper and lower densities both exist, they are not necessarily equal. But maybe that's not what you're saying?

Comment: My memory is that the natural density, if it exists, is the same as the Dirichlet density.

Comment: Refinement: natural density of a set of primes:  https://mathoverflow.net/questions/230424/if-the-natural-density-relative-to-the-primes-exists-then-the-dirichlet-densi

Comment: Analytic continuation affords a number of such examples (the [Riemann zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function) comes to mind).

Comment: Once again, not an example where two things can exist independently but only equal when they both exist

Comment: What does it mean here for something to exist?

Comment: @Allawonder : I have in mind expressions that are defined in terms of some kind of limit. A limit fails to exist if, for example, we get oscillatory behavior. Sometimes one also says that a limit fails to exist if the limit is infinite.

Comment: @hardmath: Ah, that's a good thought! Maybe make this an answer, with an explicit example of two nontrivial expressions with different but overlapping domains of convergence?

Answer (score 1):

These might be too trivial, but how about

$$\left(\sqrt{x}\right)^2 = \sqrt{x^2}$$

or

$$2 \log x = \log x^2$$

or

$$\frac{x^2-1}{x+1}=x-1$$

over $\,\Bbb R?$

If you need either side to exist when the other does not, perhaps

$$\frac{x^2-x}{x-1} = \frac{x^2+x}{x+1}$$

For something slightly less trivial, for the $\,f(x)\,$ shown below

[image: f(x)]

the equation

$$\sqrt{f(x)\hphantom{,}} = \sqrt{f(-x)\hphantom{,}}$$

would be an example. I feel there should be a relatively simple way to write f(x) without resorting to piecewise, but it's very late and my brain's not cooperating.

Comment: I like your example just above the graph. Best example so far.